# volley only post don't wait for response

Tags: android, android-volley

Can any one suggest in Android volley library only post request.
I don't want to wait for response.

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        common.toast(getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage());
        loader(false);
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
};
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tagStringReq);
```

Comment: If you don't need to wait for the response, just send null as the listener... but  wouldn't you want to at least know that the request succeeded?

Comment: I tried null but error is coming. Yes I don't want response success or fail status